# Spring MVC: ModelAttribute method is guaranteed to run before GET and POST method?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am doing a Spring Web app. I have a controller with the following methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="my", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get() {...}

@RequestMapping(value="my", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post() {...}

@ModelAttribute
public void mydata() {...}
```

This controller is for displaying a form and processing the data when the form is submitted.

My question is: is the ModelAttribute method guaranteed to run before GET method (in GET request) and POST method (in POST request)?

Regards and thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is taken from the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib) for Spring 3

> @ModelAttribute annotated methods are executed before the chosen
>   @RequestMapping annotated handler method. They effectively
>   pre-populate the implicit model with specific attributes, often loaded
>   from a database. Such an attribute can then already be accessed
>   through @ModelAttribute annotated handler method parameters in the
>   chosen handler method, potentially with binding and validation applied
>   to it.

The current documentation (for Spring 4) is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and states pretty much the same thing

> Instead @ModelAttribute methods in a controller are invoked before
>   @RequestMapping methods, within the same controller